# Holistic Tutorial or Book for jQuery MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, javascriptmvc

I'm already familiar with javascript, but am looking for a holistic tutorial or book that would teach me, from the very basics, how to create interfaces with mvc design pattern.

It should use either backbone.js or javascriptmvc framework.

ANy suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Your not going to find a book that uses backbone.js as the base of the book. A really good book though that would lay the foundation of mvc design pattern, interfaces, and design patterns in general in javascript is called JavaScript Patterns. This book really explains the language inside and out. I go so far as to say it provides much better explanation of the language than any other book out there, including JavAcript Good Parts and Definitive Guide. Also stay away from lynda.com. THeir JavaScript and PHP videos suck, especially their JavaScript.

Comment: My guess is that you pretty much know MVC and javascript but you are kind of lost in how to build/package a javascript web application? Best practices, tips, dos and donts. Am I right?

Comment: @JohnMerlino thanks for your advice. I've checked out that book on your advice and it looks great, but not quite what I'm looking for in the context of this question.

Comment: @Julien sort of. I feel like I need a more comprehensive tutorial/example to really grok it, something slightly more expansive beyond tips etc.

Comment: Ping me on twitter at @julienguimont - I am thinking about creating such tutorial/book to help with creating complete js apps.

Comment: @Julien I tried to ping you on Twitter but twitter banned me for doing so. My message probably sounded too much like spam. my tweet: http://twitter.com/#!/markstackoverfl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, finally found this:

http://andyet.net/blog/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Answer (score 2):

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/

Well, I was skeptical of the idea of JS having its own M and C but if this ALA article is correct I may have already implemented just that by accident on a couple occasions.

It's example-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Jupiter IT blog:
http://jupiterit.com/